# Using javascript queries in Morphia

Tags: mongodb, morphia

Is it possible to use a $where condition with Morphia? I have not seen it in the documentation. Here is what I'm trying to do:

```
db.products.find({$where: 'this.items.length > 0'}, {product_id:1})
```

'items' is a collection and I want to return all products that have an items collection with a count greater than zero.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Query.where()`](http://mongodb.github.io/morphia/1.2/javadoc/org/mongodb/morphia/query/Query.html#where-java.lang.String-) for that.